# Seach in an expanding range in python

Tags: python

So this is a use-case that I've run into many times, especially with coding puzzles. There is some value that I want to find in a some number space with dimensions (x,y) but I don't know the ranges.

Let me give an example:

```py
def complicated_calc(x,y):
    return found_it


for x in range(0,150):
    for y in range(-200,300):
        if complicated_calc(x,y):
            print(f"found value: {x},{y}")
            break
```

Now the numbers in the range are determined somewhat arbitrarily by what I expect the number space to be; and if it doesn't find it I'll have to expand the range. This is definitely not the most efficient way and sometimes I have to change the range settings many times before I find it. So what I would like to do is search in an expanding range, that starts around, say, `x = 50`, and expands outwards, like so:

```py
for x in expanding_range(50):
    if complicated_calc(x):
        print(f"found value: {x}")
        break
```

or for a 2D range:

```py
for x,y in 2d_expanding_range(50,50):
    if complicated_calc(x,y):
         print(f"found value: {x},{y}")
         break
```

So `expanding_range(50)` would loop the values `50, 51, 49, 52, 48, 53, 47, 54, 46, 55, 45` and so on.

Does this exist, or is there a smarter way?

Comment: I don't think there's anything built in. You can use an outer loop that iterates over the range limits that are used in the inner loops.

Comment: Since both x and y vary, what value are you supposed to find in that range? A two-dimensional value? Please show a practical example input and expected output.

Comment: Or do you mean to say you want to *calculate* (not "find") a value, with x and y as input? Unless you can invert the function, you need to either iterate over all x-y values indeed (using NumPy will be a ton faster), *or* use some minimization technique (assuming that you have some target value). The latter can be precise or imprecise, depending on the function you're calculating.

Comment: Is is guaranteed that there is a combination of x and y that can cause the `complicated_calc` function to return true? If so, perhaps consider a `while True` loop?

Comment: I think the keyword you are looking for is depth search vs breadth search. Both search methods are expanding. Depth search along one axis and width search along both axes.

Comment: Since you mention coding puzzles, this may also be very problem specific. There may be something in the actual function itself that you can use that largely avoids this search.

Comment: How is `50, 51, 49, 52, 48, 53, 47, 54, 46, 55, 45` two-dimensional?

Comment: @KellyBundy The range I posted is one dimensional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an implementation:

```py
def expanding_range(start_value):
    down = start_value
    up   = start_value+1

    while True:
      yield down
      down -= 1

      yield up
      up += 1
```

If you want to search by expanding squares from a start pair:

```py
def expanding_range_2d(start_value1, start_value2):
        yield start_value1, start_value2

        radius = 1
        while True:
            for i in range(-radius, radius):
                yield start_value1+i,      start_value2-radius
                yield start_value1+radius, start_value2+i
                yield start_value1-i,      start_value2+radius
                yield start_value1-radius, start_value2-i
            radius += 1
```

Comment: Fantastic solution. Thank you! And it's a generator!
I somehow never use classes because I have a hard time thinking of use-cases but this is a really good one. I was reluctant to selected it as the accepted answer first because it didn't actually work on my specific problem, the complicated_calc reached recursion depth, but I'm sure that is not related to expanding_range_2d() function.

Comment: @Herman I don't think it's a good case for a class. md2perpe, why not just make it a standalone generator function?

Comment: You're right, @KellyBundy. I have now simplified them to be standalone generators.

Comment: While writing it myself and testing it, I noticed you have a [bug](https://tio.run/##jVLNboMwDL7zFL5BBlSiU9Vp0t5iN4RQRgL1RENkwgp7eZZQVsrEpPpm@/uxPlkP5tSo5xdN41hSc4bWEKoK8KwbMsDbAjGvpTGSWtsB/yg8T8gSZK@5EhaaE1eVzPciaA0nk3/xupNJBHfdnr16MNeAshbwP9S7IYkL7Fp4g@Q2upywlvBOnVwEXZUNAQIqmG4J4is1miXYGrx9RYjrO2aNR5i/bvf0EB9nxhj/CSF82DzeNF90VxJzoqGL1KsIhQ03Tf2dn8ETJIcpxnyJMTmwzHOzIoKgj2BgbveNOrBfEG19wDGCI5vjdvrpkKV9Zl2KSYeai1NwmytG218zge/vPhtUgV0zNo4/).

Comment: @KellyBundy. Thanks. I had complicated things. Together we solved this.

Comment: Yep, looks good now. Btw, with `expanding_range` being infinite, @Herman's `for x in expanding_range(50): for y in expanding_range(50): ...` idea never changes `x`, so at least for 2D, it seems useless. That's why in my answer I didn't write one at first and then only added it at the end (when I realized I could have some `itertools` fun :-). Although... now that I think about it, maybe we could alternate between expanding two 1D iterators. [Rough idea of how it might progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJed3.png).

Comment: @KellyBundy yeah I realised the sequential expanding_range loops wouldn't work when I wrote the question, that's why I added the 2d variant.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two 2-dimensional iterators, with visualizations, and a faster 1-dimensional one.

Standalone generator version of @md2perpe's original answer, written a bit differently:

```
from itertools import count

def expanding_range_2d(x0, y0):
    yield x0, y0
    for radius in count(1):
        for i in range(-radius, radius):
            yield x0+i, y0-radius
            yield x0+radius, y0+i
            yield x0-i, y0+radius
            yield x0-radius, y0-i
```

Visualization with the alphabet (a-to-z, then A-Z):

```
. . . . . . . . . . .
. X . . . . . . . Y .
. . z D H L P T A . .
. . W j n r v k E . .
. . S y b f c o I . .
. . O u i a g s M . .
. . K q e h d w Q . .
. . G m x t p l U . .
. . C V R N J F B . .
. . . . . . . . . Z .
. . . . . . . . . . .
```

Code for that:

```
from string import ascii_letters as abc

grid = [['.'] * 11 for _ in range(11)]
for c, (x, y) in zip(abc, expanding_range_2d(5, 5)):
    grid[y][x] = c
for row in grid:
    print(' '.join(row))
```

Expanding differently, in increasing Manhattan distance from the starting point:

```
. . . . . P . . . . .
. . . . . z T . . . .
. . . . O n D X . . .
. . . K y f r H . . .
. W G u m b j v L . .
S C q i e a c g o A Q
. . N x l d k s E U .
. . . J t h w I Y . .
. . . Z F p M . . . .
. . . . V B . . . . .
. . . . . R . . . . .
```

Code for that:

```
def expanding_range_2d(x0, y0):
    yield x0, y0
    for radius in count(1):
        for i in range(radius):
            j = radius - i
            yield x0+i, y0-j
            yield x0+j, y0+i
            yield x0-i, y0+j
            yield x0-j, y0-i
```

Faster 1-dimensional iterator:

```
from itertools import count, chain

def expanding_range(x0):
    down = count(x0, -1)
    up = count(x0 + 1)
    return chain.from_iterable(zip(down, up))
```

[Benchmark](https://tio.run/##dZLBb8IgFMbv/SveZRG0mtZmy2LiZdclO@1mDEH7VBIKhMK0@@cd0Lppphza8H19P773iuncQavq1djzeWd1A040KByIxmjrwKJB7rLkCIfWaS3bi7nVXrkctgcuVA6ilWKLWVbjDvBkuKqF2jPL1R5ZU88NWoOkddw69sWlR7rIIKxaHxUs4cpIsjfhcSNPyiw5x4OQCJ/WYw8A6ATKOoEGITGnSxgqLl94M2wDfJLce1nfUcqOvXlVd@RU3KZMHQc1h2lJLzn/ZJjAIFt03qp@NLM4PRanxzcSybcwJOLyUEtplu282rYBskqFjyaX33WvsubZOrC0hcgDodK77dMbK0K@cf@HSDTIc0FzmBchQG/SvpjFysQm1dD6A2ZcLuZuw1XAmvQ3hUjebGq@AIUnR/4dWBbj8UsOH1ohDVvlmw3aZUnpalGtf7FDXDJ6qmblDpoWRvAExMEYSqxoSuRiHNcGSKTPGFO8QcboVb@hpfP5Bw) results for getting the first million values of `expanding_range(50)`:

```
65.5 ms  66.1 ms  66.6 ms  expanding_range_md2perpe
49.3 ms  49.8 ms  51.0 ms  expanding_range_Kelly_Bundy
```

Comment: @Herman Me, too. Was also very helpful in debugging. And look what we get when we [dot out most characters](https://pastebin.com/raw/85rfGZfn).

Comment: I was more referencing XKCD, but Monroe was in his turn referencing Dawkins again so yeah, I guess I was. https://xkcd.com/54/